# How to share data between implementation and description of a spec?

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec2

I wonder if there's any *good* way to reuse data between implementation and description of a spec... More particularly, I'd like to be able do something like the following:

```
describe "#some_method" do
  let(:arg1) { "Sample String 1" }
  let(:arg2) { "Sample String 2" }

  context "with '#{arg1}', its result" do
    specify { some_method(arg1).should == 1 }
  end

  context "with '#{arg2}', its result" do
    specify { some_method(arg2).should == 2 }
  end
end
```

Of course, this code won't work - arg1 and arg2 are not accessible outside of spec bodies.
Is it possible to achieve the similar result without using global variables or external classes?

**Update:**

I'm interested in the output of the spec. Something like this:

```
#some_method
  with 'Sample String 1' its result
    should == 1
  with 'Sample String 2' its result
    should == 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that you don't use dynamic descriptions. The RSpec way to do this would be

```
describe "#some_method" do
  it "extracts the number correctly" do
    some_method("Sample String 1").should == 1
    some_method("Sample String 2").should == 2
  end
end
```

It is no problem to hard-code test data in your specs. If you want more complete output, you can use a [custom matcher](https://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec/wiki/Custom-Matchers)

```
require 'rspec'

class Test
  def some_method(str)
    str[/[0-9]+/].to_i
  end
end

RSpec::Matchers.define :return_value_for_argument do |result, arg|
  match do |actual|
    actual.call(arg) == result
  end

  description do
    "return #{result.inspect} for argument #{arg.inspect}"
  end
end

describe Test do
  let(:test) { Test.new }
  describe "#some_method" do
    subject { test.method(:some_method) }

    it { should return_value_for_argument 1, "str 1" }
  end
end
```

Comment: Yep. But I'd like to cite arguments in the description, to produce more accurate "documentation" from the output of the spec...

Comment: Hm... output is fine now, but the whole thing looks a bit too complecated, eh? Anyway, thank you for the help!

Comment: The matcher would go in a seperate source file. This is the RSpec way, so it's as clean as it can probably get.

Comment: Yeah, separate file... this is fine if there are many methods you'r going to spec with the matcher. Otherwise, it's probably better to keep it simple.

Comment: This is why my original answer was "don't do it" ;)

Answer (score 1):

When doing API testing, I find it incredibly useful to be able to see the path, params, and response of each test. I have used [the very useful tips given by Jeff Nyman](http://testerstories.com/?p=304#comment-3180) to store things in the example.metatadata[:thing_i_want_to_store_like_url] of each test and with a custom formatter, print it out.

So my tests output look something like this:

```
 that jonathan does not know it exists
 :path  : /user/20
 :params: {}
  => response: {"error"=>{"message"=>"error", "code"=>404}}

    that jonathan cannot edit
    :path  : /user/20/update
    :params: {:name=>"evil_name"}
    => response: {"error"=>{"message"=>"error", "code"=>404}}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not appropriate to cite specific arguments in your descriptions. Your descriptions should provide a human-readable description of the desired behavior, without reference to specific arguments in most cases.